# How to add, edit and delete utterances in Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have added a few utterances and have some build errors (i think) due to not adding spaces between two slot names. When I build I get an error:

[image: Cant find a way to edit sample utterances]

How do i edit or delete the utterances or solve this error

Answer (score 1):

What had to be done is set the version next to the intent name (1) to LATEST.